# Reallocating space for a dynamically changing multi-dimensional array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc

I was just wondering how exactly I'd go about this. I know I should use `malloc`, but I'm still unsure how to go about this.

**Edit**: I realized that the function I actually would want to use is `realloc`

Each row that I'd like to allocate will have changing size, and I also want to add more rows as the program code progresses.

In case you're wondering why, I'm working on a project in which, I read a `.txt` file and then print out, the word with the highest number of appearances, as as well as the number of appearances.

Comment: @iharob how would you go about this then?

Comment: Two good solutions to your very problem appear in Knuth's “Literal Programming,” chapter 12. The first is probably the optimal way to solve this problem whereas the second example is how you would do this on Unix with a simple shell script.

Comment: @iharob I don't think you can do this without `malloc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cases where you want to read in a file of lines, I suggest you to use a linked list of lines instead of an array of lines as you can easily append to a linked list by keeping a pointer to the last element (figure this out on your own). You can later convert that linked list into an array if you like.

You could also try to figure out how long the file is going to be and allocate all the space for the entire file in one go (and then potentially read in the entire file at once) so you don't have to reallocate all the time. Again, work out the details on your own.

For your particular problem, you actually do not need to read the file into memory at all! You can save the words together with the number of occurances in a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or similar data structure and keep a link to the word with the highest count so far. It's not really complicated but the details are outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions! I'll look into these options

Comment: Unfortunately I cant upvote yet, but it did answer my question. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm happy that I was able to help you. You need a couple more points to be able to upvote things, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I have several ideas for you, depending on the dynamic behaviour of your program.

First, you could think about linked lists instead of arrays. That would make removing and adding of elements really easy. If you want to reduce the number of rows, you first have to remove all the elements in the row, then the row-element itself.

2D Matrix using linked lists:

```
[[_]] -> [[_]] -> [[_]] -> [[_]] -> [[_]]
  |        |        |        |        |
  v        v        v        v        v
 [_]      [_]      [_]      [_]      [_]
  |        |        |        |        |
  v        v        v        v        v
 [_]      [_]      [_]      [_]      [_]
  |        |        |        |        |
  v        v        v        v        v
 [_]      [_]      [_]      [_]      [_]
```

Secondly, if you usually only **ADD** elements, your rows could behave *similarly* to the C++ vector. Create each line/row with an internal variable to track the fill-level. If the structure gets full, realloc with a bigger size (there is a source that says "double the size" is a good general approach).

Datastructure that could be used instead of the linked lists (at least inside a row):

```
struct d_array(){
    int fillevel, size;
    void* memory;
}
```

This datastructure would need some function to check before each insertion, if it is full and realloc as needed. Shrinking is more difficult, you could try to run a periodic cleanup. In general, you don't want to shrink too eagerly, since the space might later be needed again (if your row grows again).

Comment: I agree, in many cases a vector-like approach is more efficient. However, linked lists could still be used to store the arrays, so that you can remove whole rows without reordering the top-level data structure.

Comment: Indeed. That's about what I say in my answer.

Comment: I was focusing more on the general idea of a dynamic, multi-dimensional array as stated in the title. However, for the given problem of word occurances, a *trie* is a much more elegant choice.

Answer (score 0):

> In case you're wondering why, I'm working on a project in which, I
>   read a .txt file and then print out, the word with the highest number
>   of appearances, as as well as the number of appearances.

You don't need multidimensional arrays for that. Text is stored sequentially, and new lines are denoted using the `\n` character.

But you will additionally need some associative container like a map, in order for you to store unique words in it as you parse the text file.

In "pseudo code":

```
for the entire text
    parse a word
        if word is not in the map insert it with count one
        else find and increment the word's count
find the word with higher count value
```

Unfortunately, C doesn't come with a map container, you will have to either [find one](http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/index.html) or write one yourself, which is probably still out of your programming abilities.

As for the parsing of a word, you could create an array of characters which represent valid text characters such as `AaBbCcDd...` and for each character of the text check if it is contained in that array. If it is contained and the previous one was not (or this is the first character) you register an index where a word begins, if it is not contained, and previously you had one that was, then you mark the end of the word, extract the word from the index range and proceed to updating it in the map. And so on until you reach the end of the text.

Last but not least, the map is actually optional. You can alternatively store word entries as a struct of a `char * word` and `int count` in a regular array, but in the case of many words lookup performance might be bad, since it will involve a lot of string comparisons, whereas a map will hash the string and lookup an integer rather than a string.